# Why ngspice doesn't accept UIC for TRAN?

Tags: spice

I'm using ngspice and trying to add `UIC` at the end of the TRAN statement, but I get an error:

```
$ ngspice 1 -> tran 10m 5 UIC
Warning:  Error: unknown parameter on .tran - ignored
```

Why does this happen and how can I make it work?

ngspice compiled from ngspice revision 20

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIC = Use Initial Conditions and is used in conjunction with the IC= specification for inductors and capacitors.

They may not support this and instead expect you to use .IC on node voltages and currents rather than on a component basis.

Answer (score 2):

NGSPICE version 20 is much too old. Please upgrade to version 26.
The current version has no problem with UIC.

PS: "ngspice 1 -> tran 10m 5 UIC" should probably be
"ngspice 1 -> tran 10m 5 0 10ms UIC" (parameters are extracted by position).